# Why is this function return empty result when I try to get column name from a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a function that should return all the column name of the table where the table name is passed in as a parameter.

I tried the query without function and it works, however once it is in the function it return empty result.

Here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_table_columns(tablename text) RETURNS SETOF information_schema.columns AS
$$
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = %s;', quote_literal(tablename));
    END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here is how I call the function:

```
SELECT * from get_table_columns('event');
```

Can anyone help on why it is not returning anything?

Thank you!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name When I run manually I can get the data, the column names and other fields all can get.

Comment: related post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/list-all-columns-for-a-specified-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `return query`:

```
BEGIN
  return query EXECUTE format(...);
END
```